# Visual hint on results page of elected community moderators

Tags: feature-request, election

Would be nice to have some kind of visual notification saying which of three moderators elected during [2012 Campaign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136817/june-2012-community-moderator-election-results) were those I had voted for.

Comment: I meant to get a screenshot, but I forgot to. I'm almost certain that the 3 that were elected were the ones I voted for. I don't remember the choice ordering though. In the end, it doesn't really matter. I think these guys are going to do a great job!

Comment: Did you mean to link to http://stackoverflow.com/election/3?

Comment: Like the thingy here: http://stackoverflow.com/election/3?tab=election ? There's a sidebar element that shows your votes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is really needed.

If you forgot who you voted for, all you have to do is visit [stackoverflow.com/election/3?tab=election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/3?tab=election) and look at the side bar on the right:

[image: screenshot]